# remove only first <br> of a div by jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying by jQuery to delete only the first `<br>` of a specific div.

I'm using the following jQuery:

```
if($(window).width() < 750 ){
    $('[data-url-id=section4]:lt(2) br').remove();
}
```

Which delete all my br instaed of the first one only from the div

If i replace the lt(2) by lt(1) or other, it does't work.

```
<h2 style="text-align:center;" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1452876314695_505"> And we’re only just beginning to see<br>
the tip of what that looks like: <br><br>
 It’s the sharing economy, internet of things,  the <br>
 quantified self,  the possibilities of virtual reality&nbsp;and robotics. It’s even shaping ideas about global
  leadership.And underneath all of this, there’s a more fundamental shift taking place, a rise
   in a new way of doing things.</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for

https://api.jquery.com/first/

```
$('[data-url-id=section4] br').first().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are now searching for the first `[data-url-id=section4]` element and then all `br`s inside that one. Instead you want to search for the first `br` element:

```
$('[data-url-id=section4] br:lt(1)').remove();
```

BTW, `lt(1)` means 'lower than 1', so only the first one (note that it's 0-based).

Comment: than you for your time, When I try this, nothing is changing unfortunately, :( IF you have any idea why ?

Comment: i got it with: $('[data-url-id=section4] br:nth-child(1)').remove(); 

Your comment helped me out, thanks a lot !

Comment: Note that `nth-child(1)` only works when it is really the first child of its parent, so if there is another element before it (which might not be a `<br>`), then it will not work.

Comment: `:lt(2)` will remove **first two** ... it is index based, not count based

Comment: @charlietfl you're right. I thought it was 1-based, like `nth-child`, but `lt` is apparently 0-based.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:first` selector, like so:

```
$('[data-url-id=section4] br:first').remove();
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vdebfgnc/)

**Ref:** [:first selector](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_first.asp)